Training Fastconformer-CTC on Kazakh Language
community. I just started working with NeMo. So, I want to train ASR based on Fastconformer-CTC with 100 hours of recorded calls in kazakh language. What type of training will be better for my situation, fine-tuning some pre-trained model or train it from scratch? Also can someone give info about the data processing and manifest?
Suggestions about Fastconformer-CTC
